# Cloning filefiled in change function

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a form include a filefield like;

[image]

Is possible? The filefile can clone (with file attached) in `change` function like ( if possible, that can change some attribute like textfield,..?)

[image]

Here is my filefile **http://jsfiddle.net/23tjk/**

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'file',
        fieldLabel: 'Upload',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        listeners:{
        'change': function(f, value){
            form.add([f]); // nothing run
        }
        }
    }],
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to achieve. What do you want to clone? Do you want a upload form with two upload fields? Do you want them to show the same content?

Comment: @Christoph i want two field have same attached file, is that possible?

Comment: I think Vlad is right. I was looking for some way to set the value of the second field, but found this in Ext JS API "Because there is no secure cross-browser way to programmatically set the value of a file input, the standard Field setValue method is not implemented." http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your field as variable:

```
var ffield = {
    xtype: 'filefield',
    fieldLabel: 'Upload',
    name: 'file[]', //<--------
    labelWidth: 50,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor: '100%',
    listeners:{
        'change': {
            fn: function(f, value) {
                form.add(ffield);
            },
            single: true // <----------
        }
    }
}
```

In your form:

```
...
items: [ffield],
...
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/23tjk/1/

Comment: srr but i want two field have same attached file, is that possible?

Comment: @trungkien No. It impossible.